How to align items on single row in ion-grid?
I would like to have the text 12345 to be vertically aligned with the avatar on the left. How to solve it first with means of ionic(while using grid) and if not possible, then with css? I've tried to set style="align-items: center;" to the ion-row without much success.

This is the minimal code I used to reproduce the issue.
Following is the code snippet to meet community standards:
<ion-grid [fixed]="true">
<ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
  <ion-col size="auto">
    <ion-avatar>
      <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/img/demos/avatar.svg" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-title><h1>12345</h1></ion-title>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Paulie_D updated my question. thanks

you should use flex for this type of lay out.

Ionic provides css utilities. https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#flex-properties. try using : ion-justify-content-center or ion-align-items-center

@Pablo, Could you explain a bit more how this works based on your code? where did you pution-justify-content-centerorion-align-items-center`?

you put those classes on any html elements, the link provides examples.

How can it work on any elements?

It seems that ionic-framework set the default margins for h1

You can override this default marigns in your app.component.css file, the following code set the h1 to margin top/bottom: 16px, margin left/right: 0px which will vertically center text 12345.
ion-col > ion-title > h1 {
  margin: 16px 0;
}

